# Blue Screen, info and image shared. Information, and prevention help needed

Tags: windows-10, bsod, window, bluescreenview

[image: BlueScreen Info]

This is some software by nirsoft but I can provide any additional info needed. What caused this bluescreen?

Comment: `ntoskrnl` is the core Windows Kernel, `MpKslDrv.sys` is possibly something to do with Windows Defender Malware protection, and `dxgkrnl.sys` is to do with the DirectX Graphics system and your graphics card. That the BSODs are almost unrelated makes me think that you need to do a memory test.

Comment: Better post online all the `.dmp` files for us to have a look. Use 7Zip to package them. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified when done.)

Comment: Okay it crashed again today, here is the link to the file [MediaFire Link to .dmp File](https://www.mediafire.com/file/buj8mtvu74ymvj0/082822-11453-01.dmp/file) `@harrymc`